# debug script loaded with getScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you debug a script that was loaded with the jquery getScript(), it does not show up in the google chrome scripts list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what are you looking for? `getScript` uses GET and should appear in the ***network tab***. It is then executed safely from within jQuery (afaik, there was an alternative to `eval`). also `getScript` also allows for a callback, which you can use to determine if the script is loaded, like say add a `console.log`?

check if that part of your code gets executed at all. your code might not have reached that part of your script.

---

[here's a demo of](http://jsfiddle.net/zWsn2/) `getScript` loading another script (kernelJS). I can see it from the resources.
[image]

Comment: The script is loaded, it works. But when trying to add a breakpoint to she reminders.js file which i am loading, i can not find the file anywhere

Comment: I added a demo in jsfiddle as well as a screenshot. and i can see the script loaded.

Comment: my code is like yours except for the fact that i have a callback function when the script is done loading. But sill i do not see it in the scripts list on chrome

Comment: The script appears in the list only when it is loaded from a different domain. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690781/debugging-scripts-added-via-jquery-getscript-function