# Source Map loads from wrong location with jQuery getScript call

Tags: javascript, jquery, source-maps

I have 2 files in this directory structure:

```
/js/app.js
/js/app.map
```

Then I load the script:

```
$.getScript("/js/app.js")
```

at the bottom of the app.js file in the source map definition:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=app.map
```

the map file is not loaded from the location `/js/app.map` and instead is loaded from `/app.map`

Why is the source map file not being loaded from the correct location? How can this be fixed?

Comment: Why don't you just change app.map to js/app.map?

Comment: this file is generated with grunt. Is there a way to get grunt to set the path to be different? As far as I can tell grunt just has a boolean option for source maps.

Comment: This is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/691661/3802281