# Force jQuery.getScript to use SCRIPT elements, never XHR

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest, getscript, script-element

This [*old* answer (circa. 2009)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/691661/2864740) indicates that [`jQuery.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) changes behavior depending on if the requested script resource / URL is domain-local or not<sup>1</sup>.

While it does provide a work-about (and there is no shortage of examples to load JavaScript elements dynamically online), I am looking for a *"2014+ jQuery 1.9/2"* approach to *avoid* using XHR/AJAX for all "get script" requests, including those that may be domain-local.

*Is it possible to **force** jQuery.getScript (or a similar "jQuery" function) to load external JavaScript via a SCRIPT element, even for local requests?*

Without much of a hack..? If the answer is "this can't be done with *standard* jQuery", then that's suitable and I'll pick one of the various alternative implementations.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Is this previous question/answer event relevant today?* A quick glance at the source makes it appear that [XHR is always used](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/ajax.js). The jQuery documentation shows a `$.ajax` equivalency, and the callbacks are all provided with a jqXHR parameter..

```
getScript: function( url, callback ) {
   return jQuery.get( url, undefined, callback, "script" );
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.9 (and likely a long bit before), the request done by `$.getScript` is *always* done via XHR and never via  `<scrip>` element. The linked "old" answer is indeed outdated and is no longer accurate.

There are many examples of how to manually use a `<script>` element available online - but there is nothing "standard" in a modern jQuery that directly supports this.